# Fill an elevation plan with multiple faces

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

I have an elevation mesh object from a svg conversion

[image]

When I proceed to fill my mesh with F shortcut I obtain a single mesh.

What I want : an individual face for each polygon

[image]

Here is the svg file link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZzRz4miXw-y4Aa-je8-VrORvlVILJY8Y/view?usp=sharing

Here is the blend file link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1APIprE6AEa84b1uPbaMmUX_PS-OmN9lz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That mesh appears to be made of large numbers of unconnected edges so it's not surprising that 'F' doesn't work! If you 'G'rab almost any edge and move it around you'll find that it isn't connected to the rest of the mesh. If you go into Edit mode, select All with 'A' and then 'M' merge by distance you'll also see that almost 2500 vertices have been merged but that has no effect on the number of disconnected edges, The reason that 'F' seems to create a single mesh is that it's just filling the outer rectangle of the whole object but all the edges inside it are still separate.

Comment: That's funny I just explained to you the same issue and how to resolve it this same way and you do the same mistake again and ask about it again, always check for disconnected vertices with svg

Comment: @MikoCG the issue is the same but the resolution method, not exactly.

Comment: because that plan is really bad for blender, I mean, there are supposed to be windows and doors right? I am not even sure where are holes supposed to be and how can you expect software to know that? You need to help it define what should be fille and what shouldn't or even fill it by parts

Comment: And now I just found out that bottom edge is 1 giant edge without vertices